# Nexus 5 togglebutton background

Tags: android, background, togglebutton

I'm using Holo light theme. When we test on Nexus 5 (4.4), the background color of togglebutton is in white, rather than in light grey. However, the togglebutton do not has white background for Nexus 7 (4.4). All other regular button are in light grey, except togglebutton on Nexus 5.

What's the problem? How can I solve it? It looks like a disabled togglebutton right now.

Just define a toggle button in activity_main.xml, and set project build target to 4.3, targetSdkVersion=18.

```
    <!-- NEXUS 5(4.4): WHITE BG, NEXUS 7(4.4): GREY BG //-->
    <ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/toggleTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:textOff="OFF"  />

    <!-- NEXUS 5(4.4): GREY BG, NEXUS 7(4.4): GREY BG //-->
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    />
```

Nexus 7 (any other Android device) toggle button

[image: Nexus 7 (any other Android device) toggle button]

Nexus 5 toggle button

[image: Nexus 5 toggle button]

Comment: I just created a new android application with a blank activity from eclipse, I don't expect it will behave differently for different devices. How can I make it consistent for all devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sdk, the 9 patch for btn_toggle_on_normal_holo_light in the xxhdpi fold
er is white. This is a bug that you will have to work around. Probably the easiest way is to use the [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Click on Toggle and customize the color if you wish to suit your app. Include the nine patches from the generated zip, and problem solved!